# Query too slow with Include graph

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

I'm trying to retrieve 60.000 record about from my SQL Server through EF 6.

I need to include all relationships of my primary entity without using lazy loading, for instance:

Primary Entity: User
User Graph: Hobbies (Collection)
User Graph: Work (Object)
User Graph: SomeOtherGraph (Collection)
and so on...

for a total of 8 object graph.

Note that each every graph, contains in turn a reference to the primary entity (User) as collection (for one to many relations) or as single entity (for one to one relations).

I think my issue is due to all this circular reference that entity framework builds for me.

Is there some way to get my relationship without circular reference?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Surely it's just too many `Includes`, nothing to do with circular references. But who can tell without seeing the actual classes?

Comment: As far as I know the only way to solve my issue is to use DTO and create a mapping manually. by this way, I'll get down all my relationship of first level only, without any circular reference. Isn't it?

Comment: "I revert to my former statement".

Comment: Can you expand on what you're using this for?

Comment: I've solved with DTO and projection selection. That's the only way I know to get it worked in less time as possibile.